# Chrome Console - Which shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-console

I wondered what was the differences in Chrome, using :

- Ctrl+Shift+I,
- Ctrl+Shift+J,
- Ctrl+Shift+C (ok, it's focused on elements)
- F12

Is there any ?

Thanks

Nb : reading [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts), it's about the same exactly ?? Why three shortcuts, then ?